# Update comma separated list in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update a comma separated list in mysql. My query goes like:

```
UPDATE courses SET c_subscribers = c_subscribers,129 WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET (1270, c_subscribers) AND c_id = 129
```

I am getting an MySql Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Which i cant figure out why? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The pains of non-normalized design, comma-separated lists in a column are always painful to workround the problems that they cause

Comment: try relations instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this....

```
UPDATE courses SET c_subscribers = CONCAT(c_subscribers,',129') WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET (1270, c_subscribers) AND c_id = 129
```

using `CONCAT` function you can update the required value

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10791870)

Comment: @G4M1TG: It's terse and not a bit too specific - but how on Earth does it *not* answer the question?